# Programs works on my pc, but not server

Tags: java, database, jar, version, program-entry-point

I have a program i've written and turned into a jar file. The jar file works just fine on my computer. When I try to run the program on the server it will be running on, the jar file doesn't work. I get this error.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Publish
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Publish
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: Publish. Program will exit.
```

I think this problem is caused by different versions of java or different environments or something. I think the libraries are not the problem here, but the environments where this program is being run. The jar file works perfectly on my own computer.

My java version
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

Server java version
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)

I also get this error, which suggests that I may have a 32 bit java while the server has a 64 bit and this might be causing problem.

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap

I got around this error easily by just allocating some memory to running this process.

Does anyone have any idea about how to fix this problem?

Note: i also looked at the manifest file and it seems fine

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Publish` without the package. This means java expects this class in default package.

You need to use the fully qualified name, for instance: `foo.bar.Publish`

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html):

> By default, the first non-option argument is the name of the class to
>   be invoked. A fully-qualified class name should be used. If the -jar
>   option is specified, the first non-option argume nt is the name of a
>   JAR archive containing class and resource f iles for the application,
>   with the startup class indicated by the Main-Class manifest header.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the full package name. This error is not that of 32/64 bit OS's, or differences in Java Environments.